# Database Mirroring canot be removed error SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Ive a database which was mirrored before and now its showing as principal, disconnected/in recovery and we need to restore a back up into it.
Since restore option is disabled,for that purpose I tried to remove the mirroring from MS and whole properties are shows as greyed out disabled.

I tried

```
alter database mydb set partner off;
```

which returned

> The operating system returned error 21(The device is not ready.) to
>   SQL Server during a read at offset 0000000000000000 in file 'ldf file
>   path'. Additional messages in the SQL Server error log and system
>   event log may provide more detail. This is a severe system-level error
>   condition that threatens database integrity and must be corrected
>   immediately. Complete a full database consistency check (DBCC
>   CHECKDB). This error can be caused by many factors; for more
>   information, see SQL Server Books Online.

So I tried

```
alter database mydb set offline;
```

which returned

> Msg 1468, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The operation cannot be performed on database "mydb" because it is involved in a database mirroring session or an availability group.
>   Some operations are not allowed on a database that is participating in
>   a database mirroring session or in an availability group.
>
> Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   ALTER DATABASE statement failed.

Then I tried to restore the DB from the backup file in recovery

```
RESTORE DATABASE Inetcat_mhra
   FROM DISK = '.bak location'
   WITH REPLACE,RECOVERY
```

which returned error

> Msg 3104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 RESTORE cannot operate on database
>   'mydb' because it is configured for database mirroring or has joined
>   an availability group. If you intend to restore the database, use
>   ALTER DATABASE to remove mirroring or to remove the database from its
>   availability group. Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 RESTORE
>   DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: What is the exact status of the mirror through `Database Mirroring Monitor` ?

Comment: By the way, what is the reason of the Mirror to be "broken" ?

Comment: And also, did you try the `DBCC CHECKDB` on the involved database ?

Comment: @Hybris95 Sorry for the delay in reply.. Its really strange.. you know.. when we try to make it offline.. its say there is mirroring.. and when we try to remove mirroring by the above code its saying like mirroring is not there..

Comment: You should try asking for this on dba.stackexchange.com